# create list of tuples with download url + "href"

Tags: python, string, python-requests, tuples, urllib3

I'm trying to make a list of tuples, the first element being the download URL and the second being the file name from the URL string with below code:

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import io
url = r"https://www.ers.usda.gov/data-products/livestock-meat-domestic-data"
my_bytes = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
my_bytes = my_bytes.read().decode("utf8")
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(my_bytes, features = "lxml")
table_data = parsed_html.body.find('table', attrs = {'id':'data_table'})
download_url = "https://www.ers.usda.gov"
full_download_url = [tuple(download_url,i["href"]) for i in table_data.find_all('a')]
```

But I've been getting `TypeError: must be str, not list` all along and I'm not sure how to fix this, please help? Thanks!

Comment: What does `[i]["href"]` mean to you? Can you explain what that expression is doing, in your own words?

Comment: it's giving me all excel and csv download links without the initial piece of it, but I just realized it was bad so I changed it to i instead of [i] and it's not finally working because `TypeError: must be str, not list` but when I change it to str it goes letter by letter :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly accessing the `download_url` array index.

Python is interpreting your code as creating an array with one element `[0]` when `i` is
0 for example, and then trying to access the element `["href"]` which is a string, not a valid index

If you specify `download_url` before accessing the indices it will work as expected

```
full_download_url = [(download_url, download_url[i]["href"]) for i in table_data.find_all('a')]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: That is likely because the element at download_url[i] is a string, not a dictionary. But it is impossible to tell without more information (Such as what the value of download_url is)

Comment: download_url = `"https://www.ers.usda.gov"` and I was aiming to add [(i["href"]) for i in table_data.find_all('a')] but as it's got to be a string it takes it letter by letter when I try to add both pieces to a tuple

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the desired output would be with `download_url = "ers.usda.gov"`?

Comment: `'https://www.ers.usda.gov/webdocs/DataFiles/51875/MeatStatsRecent.xlsx?v=1347'` but no worries, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-a-tuple-to-a-string/ helped me get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I needed:

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import io
url = r"https://www.ers.usda.gov/data-products/livestock-meat-domestic-data"
my_bytes = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
my_bytes = my_bytes.read().decode("utf8")
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(my_bytes, features = "lxml")
table_data = parsed_html.body.find('table', attrs = {'id':'data_table'})
download_url = "https://www.ers.usda.gov"
def convertTuple(tup):
    str = ''
    for item in tup:
        str = str + item
    return str
full_download_url = [convertTuple(tuple(download_url + i["href"])) for i in table_data.find_all('a')]
```

Thanks to [Geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-a-tuple-to-a-string/) and everyone trying to help :)